# React native, passing variables from other files

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I am having trouble passing variables from one file to another.

module.exports works great when passing classes. 
However is there any way in native to pass variables from file to file by exporting?

In the example below, one file (button) is creating an array of random numbers and I want to access that array in another file (genreSelector). Similarly I am trying to pass an array of strings from (genre to genreSelector).

I cant find an example of how to do this so I am under the impression that it isn't possible. How should I be passing information if this isn't possible?
Do I need to have all the functions in my main and call them from within the child classes, if so how do I reference the function of the parent class rather than its own this.function?

So main is rendered in index.android.js and it all works great. Bar of course the passing of arrays from file to file. I tried using states but still cant access the variables as desired.

Apologies for such a basic question asked in such a complicated way.

```
//this is button.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/styles.js';

 let rNumbers = [1,2,3];
var Button = React.createClass({

    rNumberGen: function(){
        let rNumbers = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.rNumberGen} style={styles.center}>
                        <Text style={styles.button}>Generate!</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
    }

});

module.exports = rNumbers;
module.exports = Button;
```

//this is genreSelector

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import{
    genre1,
    genre2,
    genre3
} from './genres.js';
import rNumbers from './button.js';
import styles from '../styles/styles.js';

 let a = rNumbers.toString();
 Alert.alert('This is', a);

var Genre = React.createClass({

    render: function(){

        let genre = this.props.selected;
        return(
                <View style={styles.genre}>
                    <Text style={styles.center}>{genre}</Text>
                </View>
            );
    }
});

module.exports = Genre;
```

//This is main.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
   AppRegistry,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View
 } from 'react-native';
 import
     Button
  from './button.js';
 import
     Genre
     // genres
  from './genreSelector.js';
 import
     styles
  from '../styles/styles.js';


class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Genre Genrerator</Text>

            <Text style={[styles.h2, styles.h21]}>I am listening to</Text>
            <View style={styles.genreContainer}>
                 <Genre selected='{genres[1]}'/>
                 <Genre selected='{genres[2]}'/>
                 <Genre selected='{genres[3]}'/>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.h2}>You filthy casual</Text>
            <Button/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

 module.exports = Main;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
module.exports = rNumbers;
module.exports = Button;
```

You are overwriting it by assigning like that. You should use export keyword:

```
export {rNumbers};
export {Button};
```

then import like so:

```
import {rNumbers} from './button.js';
import {Button} from './button.js';
```

edit: error: expected { after export. Added in

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped massively. 
Do you know if it is possible to export each time the button calls the:

'rNumberGen: function(){
        let rNumbers = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
    },'

The export works but it does not update when there is a change made to rNumbers

Comment: Also if you would like to edit your export for anyone who follows this. 
it must be in the form export {rNumbers}; export {Button};

Comment: Import export is to pull in code essentially, it is not a way to pass live objects around. I would suggest you use some kind of a store that you pass around through function calls.

Comment: I use mobx for storage myself, some people prefer redux

Comment: Another option is to store it in the state of the Main component and passing it down to button and Button's function can then modify it

Comment: Thank you for all your help Peter, got started with mobx yesterday and just figuring things out for now. It was the sort of storage I desired

Comment: There's a really good free course on egghead.io that covers mobx