# How to get values from one Js file to another in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to use the **selectedValue** from File2.js to be assigned to **Pool** in File1.js. I have tried using Props, Context, Passing the value directly, It wouldn't work.

Also, I think I have messed up the execution order of DropdownMenu (It's value gets updated after it's used when I tried using it.).

What I want to do is, pass the value obtained from dropdown menu in File1 as Index of a parsed file in I am importing.
I am using React and I can't seem to get it right. Please help a noob out.

#### File1.js

```
const genes = ['CY5','ROX','HEX','FAM']; 
var amp_values = parser.amp_values;

const colors = ['rgb(255,195,0)','rgb(32,243,31)','rgb(31,243,232)', 'rgb(238,31,243)'];
const bdcolor = ['rgba(255,195,0,0.3)','rgba(32,243,31,0.3)','rgba(31,243,232,0.3)', 'rgba(238,31,243,0.3)'];
var datasets = [];
var Pool = 0; //HERE
var i = Pool;

for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
  datasets[j] = {label:genes[j],data:amp_values[j][i],fill:false, backgroundColor: colors[j%colors.length], borderColor: bdcolor[j%bdcolor.length]}
}

const data = {
  labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45],
  datasets: datasets,
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxes: {
      display: false
    },
  },
};


const LineChart = () => (
  <>
    <div>
      <div className='header'>
        <h1>Gene Pooling Plot</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='menu'>
       <DropdownMenu/>
      </div>
      <div >
        <Line className="chart" data={data} options={options} height='600' width='1000'/>
     </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

#### File2.js

```
const options = parser.pool_listed;

class DropdownMenu extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {selected: ''}
    this._onSelect = this._onSelect.bind(this)
  }

  _onSelect (option) {
    //console.log('You selected ', option.label)
    this.setState({selected: option})
  }

 
 render () {
    const defaultOption = this.state.selected
    const selectedValue = typeof this.state.selected === 'string' ? defaultOption : this.state.selected.label
    return (
      <section>
        <h3>Select pool value: </h3>
        <Dropdown options={options} onChange={this._onSelect} value={selectedValue} placeholder="Select an option"/>
        {selectedValue}
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native, passing variables from other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345214/react-native-passing-variables-from-other-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can define state and on_select function in File1 and pass on_delect function to File2 as a prop.
This way when you call `onchange={on_select}` it will update the state and you will get selected value in file 1